# I am trying to tag my AWS glue job using aws cli where key name is "My key" and value is "job1" , Key name will be "My key "

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

```sh
aws glue tag-resource --resource-arn arn:aws:glue:us-east-2:myaccountid \
--tags-to-add 
'key="My key",value=job1'
```

It is throwing  syntax error !

Answer (score 0):

[aws glue tag-resource](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/glue/tag-resource.html#tag-resource)

```sh
aws glue tag-resource --resource-arn arn:aws:glue:us-east-2:myaccountid:job/jobname  \
--tags-to-add KeyName1=string,KeyName2=string
```

```sh
aws glue tag-resource --resource-arn arn:aws:glue:us-east-2:myaccountid:job/jobname \
--tags-to-add '{"key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2"}'
```

[AWS Tags in AWS Glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-tags.html)

Comment: I want to have a white space in my key name like this : Key Name1=string,Key Name2=string ?Is it possible

Comment: @Monalisingh yes you can have, use the second option then or you can just enclose your key in quotes while executing the command

Comment: tried this , it shows unknown options :( --->  aws glue tag-resource --resource-arn arn:aws:glue:us-east-2:acountid:job/mygluejobname --tags-to-add '{"key 1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2"}' ....even normal syntax is not working ,ie, aws glue tag-resource --resource-arn arn:aws:glue:us-east-2:acountid:job/mygluejobname --tags-to-add '{"key1" : "value1", "key2 ": "value2"}'

Comment: @Monalisingh you are missing a quote on `"key2 : "value2"}`

Comment: Sorry I missed here but while in  command I used properly  like this :  aws glue tag-resource --resource-arn arn:aws:glue:us-east-2:acountid:job/mygluejobname --tags-to-add '{"key 1" : "value1", "key 2" : "value2"}'          ...............

Comment: @Monalisingh can you try this `aws glue tag-resource --resource-arn arn:aws:glue:us-east-2:myaccountid \
--tags-to-add 'Key Name1'='value','Key Name2'='value2'` that's strange it is failing.

Comment: yes , Its failing in either ways , When I am removing the space from the key name it works but when I am adding space in my key name it does not (Ex: Key name ), I am wondering if AWS supports spaces in key name or not ?

Comment: @Monalisingh I just created the tag using the same command in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/toddlers/f6cf4a1b761825ef83a47d099c1ac21c) you can see, it works.

Comment: I am trying in AWS CLI, the same way like you have done in GIT  but getting the same error, Are you using AWS CLI or any other tool for running the commands? Appreciate your help

Comment: @Monalisingh then the trouble might be in the CLI version you are using. I am using `aws-cli/1.18.65 Python/3.7.3 Darwin/20.3.0 botocore/1.17.60`